# CraftCMS Push Notifications: New Device Token

Tags: plugins, plugin-pushnotifications

I've been looking at the Push Notification Plugin.

Link: https://github.com/boboldehampsink/pushnotifications

I'm having some issues determining how an iOS or Android application can automatically add a new device token to an application. Meaning, I wouldn't want to add the device token via the CP. Most users don't know what their device token is.

I've looked at the HTTP Requests that is produced when I click to create a new device in the plugin settings; however, when I test trying to create a new device only by URL it fails. Any ideas?

Has anyone else used this plugin?

Comment: Maybe try creating an issue on the repo? https://github.com/boboldehampsink/pushnotifications/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally figured this out with the help of the developer, boboldehampsink. Thank you so much for your help!

The post parameters are:

```
{
    'app': 'app_handle',
    'platform': 'ios/android',
    'registrationId': 'token'
}
```

**Note:**

You must use the front-end url to register a device without needing login credentials.

Post to the URL:
http://localhost/CraftCMS/public/actions/pushNotifications/devices/registerDevice

**More information found here:** https://github.com/boboldehampsink/pushnotifications/issues/1